# Determining the quarter that a date falls in when quarters are based on a random start date

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Lets say I have a contract that has a start and end date of 2/1/2016 through 1/31/2017

The quarters are determined based on the start date of the contract so it is different then just using normal calendar quarters.

Q1: FEB MAR APR
Q2: MAY JUN JUL
Q3: AUG OCT SEPT
Q4: NOV DEC JAN

With normal calendar quarters I can simply do: `(date.Month + 2) / 3;`

How can I do it in this case?

Comment: Is that supposed to be "through 1/31/2017"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something more general like this?

```
var quarter = (((checkDate.Year * 12 + checkDate.Month - 1) - (startDate.Year * 12 + startDate.Month - 1)) / 3) % 4 + 1;
```

Here is an approach that would take the current day of month into account:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Contract
    {
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public int CurrentQuarter
        {
            get
            {
                var now = DateTime.Now.Date;
                var month = (now.Year*12 + now.Month - 1) - (StartDate.Year*12 + StartDate.Month - 1);
                if (now.Day < StartDate.Day) month--;
                var quarter = (month / 3) + 1;
                return quarter;
            }
        }
        // ...
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var contract = new Contract { StartDate = new DateTime(2016, 1, 12) };
            Console.WriteLine("Current contract quarter is {0}", contract.CurrentQuarter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution seems good, but lets say the contract starts on 2/21/2016 then Q1 would consist of: 2/21 through 4/21. In this case if the checkDate is 4/22/2016 it should be Q2, but it is returning as Q1 with your function. How can I make it so the day is included?

Comment: Tell me if adding this after your formula should do the trick: if checkDate.Day > startDate.Day ? quarter = quarter + 1 : quarter. I haven't been able to break it yet.

Comment: @BlakeRivell yes I thought about that too. I think you're on the right track, but take a look at the second approach I added.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same logic as you had been, just subtract out the starting month of the contract first. Of course, you'll need to account for dates in the next year, also. Those will always be negative if you just subtract months, so you can use a check for negative to indicate it's the next year, and compensate. So, for the example you gave:

```
var startMonth = 2;
var date = DateTime.Now; //Or whatever date to check
var monthDiff = date.Month - startMonth;
if (monthDiff < 0)
{
    monthDiff += 12;
}
var quarter = (monthDiff + 3) / 3;
```

Comment: Obviously, this will only work if the contract is for a year or less. If it needs to handle longer contracts, the code would need to be beefed up to look at the years of the start and "to check" dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
((date.Month + 10) / 3)  % 4;
```

Comment: This seems like the cleanest answer, but I don't see how it could possibly work without the contract start date being a parameter. There is going to be 2 parameters to this new helper function I create: One of them being the contract start date and the other being the date of which you want to know what quarter it falls in.